# Using v-model for Two-Way Binding in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, promise

I'm trying to make a simple converter, that is, the user inputs the amount and the price gets converted.  Suppose I have an input field on my website:

```html
<input type="number" v-model="coin_amount" id="usd" placeholder="Amount (USD)">
```

And `convert()` function that converts `coin_amount` to another currency

```js
convert() {
  axios({
    method: "GET",
    "url": "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + this.input.cryptocurrency + "/"
  }).then(result => {
    this.coin_amount = this.coin_amount / result.data[0].price_usd;
  }, error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  return this.coin_amount;
}
```

And i display the converted value like this:

```html
<span><strong>Value:</strong> {{ coin_amount }}</span>
```

How can I invoke the `convert()` function so that it can convert the amount while typing (LIVE). I thought to use `v-model` but it just shows the inputted amount, not the converted one. I also thought to use a special convert button and invoke it with `v-on:click="convert()` but I want to make it more advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Computed

It would be easiest to use a `computed` instead of a `convert` method:

```
computed: {
  converted() {
    // do stuff with `this.coin_amount` 
    // return the converted value
  }
}
```

Then in your template, show that computed property:

```html
<span><strong>Value:</strong>{{ converted }}</span>
```

---

EDIT FOR ASYNC:

But now you've edited your question to show your converting code, and it's async.

**Option 1**

Since computeds are sync only, to continue using it async, you would need a solution like [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed).  I would use the next option instead but here is what your code would look like using that package with your converting code:

```
asyncComputed: {
  async converted() {
    const result = await axios({ method: "GET", url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + this.input.cryptocurrency + "/" });
    return this.coin_amount / result.data[0].price_usd;
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

Or you could use a `watch`, which are allowed to be async.  In this example, `converted` is a data variable set by the watch, not a computed:

```js
data() {
  coin_amount: null,
  converted: null,
  // ...   
},
watch: {
  async coin_amount(val) {
    const result = await axios({ method: "GET", url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + this.input.cryptocurrency + "/" });
    this.converted = this.coin_amount / result.data[0].price_usd;
  }
}
```